# Firestore rules working in simulator but not on website

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create some rules for my Firestore database. When I run these rules in the simulator on firebase console, everything works fine. Yet when I deploy the rules and try it out on my website, I get a permission denied error in the console.

The data I am trying to access is stored like this:

*1.  /teams/{teamId}*

*2.  /teams/{teamId}/boards/{boardId}*

where `{teamId}` and `{boardId}` are auto-generated ID´s:

E.g:

*/teams/JTUrZcqz9Z20JuyCCcnV*

*/teams/JTUrZcqz9Z20JuyCCcnV/boards/OfcLPZItCk6Li7OeXwwt*

I am trying to iterate through all of these children.

**Firestore database:**
[image: Firestore database in console]

[image: Firestore databse in console]

**firestore.rules:**

```
 match /teams/{teamId} {
   allow read: if isMemberOfTeam(teamId);
   allow write: if true; // memberOfTeam(teamId);

  match /boards/{boardID} {
   allow read: if memberOfTeam(teamId) || boardIsPublic(teamId);
   allow write: if memberOfTeam(teamId);

    match /{document=**} {
     allow read: if memberOfTeam(teamId) || boardIsPublic(teamId);
     allow write: if memberOfTeam(teamId);
     }
  }
  match /{document=**} {
   allow read: if isMemberOfTeam(teamId); // memberOfTeam(teamId);
   allow write: if true; // memberOfTeam(teamId);
  }
 }

function isMemberOfTeam(teamId) {
    return  get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/$(teamId)).members[request.auth.uid].isMember;
}
function boardIsPublic(teamId) {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/$(teamId)).data.isPublic;
}
```

**Code in website:**
Firestore query:

```
ref.where('members.' + user.uid + '.isMember', '==', true)
```

All code:

```
this.teamsCollection = this.auth.user$.filter(user => user != null)
  .map(user => this.afs.collection<TeamsInterface>('teams', ref => ref.where('members.' + user.uid + '.isMember', '==', true)))
  .shareReplay(1);
this.$teams = this.teamsCollection.switchMap(collection => collection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
  return actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as TeamsInterface;
    data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return data;
  });
}));
```

**Error I get in console:**

> Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: Please include the code you are using to test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why, but everything works with this code:

```
match /teams/{teamId} {
      allow read: if isMemberOfTeam(existingData());
      allow update: if isMemberOfTeam(existingData()); // memberOfTeam(teamId);
      allow create: if isSignedIn();

      match /archived/{boardID} {
        allow read: if isMemberOfTeam(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/$(teamId)).data) 
              || boardIsPublic(existingData());
        allow write: if isMemberOfTeam(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/$(teamId)).data);
      }

      match /boards/{boardID} {
        allow read: if isMemberOfTeam(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/$(teamId)).data) 
              || boardIsPublic(existingData());
        allow write: if isMemberOfTeam(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/$(teamId)).data);

        // match /beta {
        //   allow write: if memberOfTeam(teamId) || boardIsPublic(teamId);
        // }

        // All subcollection
        match /{document=**} {
          allow read: if isMemberOfTeam(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/$(teamId)).data) 
                || boardIsPublic(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/$(teamId)).data);
          allow write: if isMemberOfTeam(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/$(teamId)).data);
         }
      }

     }
```